# Samsung J1 Ace cant enter recovery mode

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, recovery-mode, factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-j1

My phone J1 Ace is stuck on boot logo with red signal. I can't go to the recovery mode to flash. What can I do now?

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

Please press power button for 30 -45 second
Or remove battery